# Use data from other multiple data files with calculations

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, calculations

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53228/12440) shows nicely how to use data from another file while plotting data using `\addplot table`. However, when trying to access the `create on use` column using `\thisrow{}`, an error occurs. For example, simply plotting the column `newZ` below works, but dividing `Y` by `newZ` fails with the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `newZ__column_not_found'
```

I'd guess that this is somewhat expected because the pgfplots manual states `\thisrow` can only be used with *"an existing column or one for which a column
alias exists"*, but it says nothing about automatically created columns.

So, is there another way to do calculations with columns from another file that I'm not aware of?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data1.dat}
X  Y
1  3
2  2
3  1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{data2.dat}
Z
4
7
2
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotstableset{
    create on use/newZ/.style={
        create col/copy column from table={data2.dat}{Z}
    }   
}   

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot table [y=newZ] {data1.dat};
% This fails:
%\addplot table [y expr=\thisrow{Y} / \thisrow{newZ}] {data1.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interestingly, I asked a related question here just the other day: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/198253/32374

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that question. Actually I'd go so far as to say that mine is a duplicate, not just related. The solution you posted also solves my problem. :-)

Comment: Glad to help! I think we should leave this one open for a bit in case someone comes along to answer it :-)